# How to extract nested XMLType Data from Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, xmltype

I have following xml data stored in xmltype column in database.

```
<TRNXS_DTL transactionSeq="1">
  <TRNX_ITEM sequence="1" name="ERROR_CODE" value="2009"/>
  <TRNX_ITEM sequence="2" name="ERROR_DESC" value="Data Not Found for given record id."/>
</TRNXS_DTL>
```

Now I tried querying database using extract as under:

```
  SELECT SRC_DSC_TXT as "TXT",   
  TYPE_CODE as "Code",   
  PID as "Participant ID",   
  SYS_ID as "System",   
  CHANEL as "Channel",   
  to_char(crt_ts,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "Timestamp (MST)",   
  extract(TRX_DATA, '/TRNXS_DTL/TRNX_ITEM/text()') as "DETAILS"
  FROM PARTICIPANT_DATA,   
  WHERE SRC_VAL_TXT   =TYPE_CD;
```

But when i run above query i get null under Details column, any thoughts?

Comment: I am open to add more details and I certainly appreciate negative vote but it would be helpful if down voter can add comment as to why negative vote.

Comment: so that I can update question accordingly.

Comment: I dont know much about XML columns, but is this acceptable way to store one? `<TRNX_ITEM sequence="1" name="ERROR_CODE" value="2009"/>` 
I mean shouldn't there be an end tag `/TRNX_ITEM` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  tag in your XML doesn't have any text. It has three attributes: sequence, name and value.
So, your query is returning NULL.

Consider the following example.

```
create table myt(
type_code number,
trx_data xmltype
);

insert into myt values(101,
'<TRNXS_DTL transactionSeq="1">
  <TRNX_ITEM sequence="1" name="ERROR_CODE" value="2009"/>
  <TRNX_ITEM sequence="2" name="ERROR_DESC" value="Data Not Found for given record id."/>
</TRNXS_DTL>'
);

insert into myt values(102,
'<TRNXS_DTL transactionSeq="1">
  <TRNX_ITEM sequence="1" name="ERROR_CODE" value="2010">NNN</TRNX_ITEM>
  <TRNX_ITEM sequence="2" name="ERROR_DESC" value="Data Found for given record id.">OOO</TRNX_ITEM>
</TRNXS_DTL>'
);

SQL> select  * from myt;       

 TYPE_CODE TRX_DATA
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       101 <TRNXS_DTL transactionSeq="1">
             <TRNX_ITEM sequence="1" name="ERROR_CODE" value="2009"/>
             <TRNX_ITEM sequence="2" name="ERROR_DESC" value="Data Not Found for given record id."/>
           </TRNXS_DTL>

       102 <TRNXS_DTL transactionSeq="1">
             <TRNX_ITEM sequence="1" name="ERROR_CODE" value="2010">NNN</TRNX_ITEM>
             <TRNX_ITEM sequence="2" name="ERROR_DESC" value="Data Found for given record id.">OOO</TRNX_ITEM>
           </TRNXS_DTL>
```

for type_code 102 has NNN and OOO as text.

```
SQL> select type_code,
extract(trx_data, '/TRNXS_DTL/TRNX_ITEM/text()').getStringVal() as "DETAILS"
from myt; 

 TYPE_CODE DETAILS
---------- -------------
       101
       102 NNNOOO
```

You can see that, it concatenates the text from both the  tags.

In case, you are after the attribute values, you can use `@` to specify the attribute.

```
SQL> select type_code,
extract(trx_data, '/TRNXS_DTL/TRNX_ITEM/@value').getStringVal() as "DETAILS"
from myt; 

 TYPE_CODE DETAILS
---------- ------------------------------------------
       101 2009Data Not Found for given record id.
       102 2010Data Found for given record id.
```

Again, as you can see, the text is concatenated.

If you want them in separate columns, you need to give a predicate to conditionally restrict the node that is selected.

```
SQL> select type_code,
extract(trx_data, '/TRNXS_DTL/TRNX_ITEM[@sequence="1"]/text()').getStringVal() as "DETAILS",
extract(trx_data, '/TRNXS_DTL/TRNX_ITEM[@sequence="2"]/text()').getStringVal() as "DETAILS2"
from myt;

 TYPE_CODE DETAILS                  DETAILS2
---------- ------------------------ --------------
       101
       102 NNN                      OOO


SQL> select type_code,
extract(trx_data, '/TRNXS_DTL/TRNX_ITEM[@sequence="1"]/@value').getStringVal() as "DETAILS",
extract(trx_data, '/TRNXS_DTL/TRNX_ITEM[@sequence="2"]/@value').getStringVal() as "DETAILS2"
from myt;

 TYPE_CODE DETAILS                  DETAILS2
---------- ------------------------ ------------------------------------------
       101 2009                     Data Not Found for given record id.
       102 2010                     Data Found for given record id.
```